# Holmgren's theorem on the boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, parabolic-pde

Consider $\Omega$ a bounded Lipschitz domain, with $\gamma \subseteq \partial \Omega$ a $C^2$ manifold. I am interested in proving the following.

> Let $u: \Omega\times [0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a classical solution to the heat equation $u_t -\Delta u =0$ that is continuous up to the boundary, and suppose $u, \partial_\nu u =0$ on $\Sigma:=\gamma \times [T_0,T_1]$. Is it true that $u=0$ in the whole space time cylinder?

I was looking for an answer by Holmgren's uniqueness theorem. Indeed, $\Sigma$ is surely non-characteristic for $\partial_t - \Delta$, the smoothness of $\Sigma$ also implies that all first order derivatives of $u$ vanish there.

The global version of Holmgren's therorem proved by Fritz John ([theorems 1, 2 here](https://books.google.it/books?id=QRXSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q&f=false)) seems to allow my conclusion, provided $\Sigma$ is in the interior of $\Omega\times(0,T)$, which is not the case.

Can something be said for my case? I suspect that one would want to continue $u$ outside of its domain of definition in such a way that $u$ solves the same equation, but I don't see a straightforward way to do so. Do you have any hints and possibily references for the employed theorems? Thank you.

Comment: The full space gradient vanishes on $\Sigma$ and then all second derivatives like $D^2_{\tau,\sigma}$ where at least one among $\tau, \sigma$ is tangential to $\partial \Omega$. From the equation, since also $u_t$ vanishes, then all second derivatives are zero on $\partial \Omega$ (the computations when the boundary is the half space are elementary, for general $\Omega$ less pleasant). Then you can continue $u$ by zero across $\Sigma$ and get a solution of the heat equation which is zero in an open set. By analiticity in $x$ you get that $u=0$ in $[T_0,T_1] \times \Omega$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune What smoothness up to the boundary do we need on $u$ for these computations? As far as I know we only have space-time smoothness in the interior, analyticity in the interior of temporal slices, continuity up to the boundary.

Comment: We need $C^{1,2}$ up to the boundary for that while you need less (but at least $C^{0,1}$ ) to formulate the question. The approach via Carleman estimates should require less, but I am not an expert.